# PayPal SandBox in Laravel

Tags: controller, paypal-sandbox, laravel-7, paypal-rest-sdk

My SandBox settings are like below

[image]

My .env code is like below

```
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID=Afr4Ig_nu8QUTt3uPBJW-VLEQoBTdS_OjGqZIXtM4FLWZpLNamAEo6NtTbHeB-_WWwESBdioqQNZW1Kw
PAYPAL_SANDBOX_SECRET=EMHy-4TQ5C6O8qA8ZittO-XhdJ-xM-PUuHR2f6oRBlVqR9MB26WDYtkjdR4ejhQpKPyLZpGmwxMTSXSA
```

I am trying to access  them like below in one of my controller

```
if(config('paypal.settings.mode') == 'live'){
            $this->client_id = config('paypal.live_client_id');
            $this->secret = config('paypal.live_secret');
        } else {
            $this->client_id = config('paypal.sandbox_client_id');
            $this->secret = config('paypal.sandbox_secret');
        }

        echo $this->client_id;

        die();
```

But I am getting blank white screen.

Comment: Your ".env code" has no relation to what you are doing in your controller, or if it does you aren't showing that part of your code.  You should turn on PHP errors and do basic debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a file called paypal.php in your config folder.

The content of that file could look similar to the following:

```
<?php

return [
    'settings' => [
        'mode' => 'sandbox'
    ],
    'sandbox_client_id' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_CLIENT_ID', ''),
    'sandbox_secret' => env('PAYPAL_SANDBOX_SECRET', '')
]
```

This will load the values from your environment and make them available with the config function calls you provided.